# How to define step function name on aws when creating it from a metaflow flow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, netflix-metaflow

I have a metaflow flow which I want to create a step function on aws for it
but I want to create 2 step functions to the same flow twice, one as a staging environment and another as production (MY_FLOW_STG and MY_FLOW_PRD)

the command we have to create the step function is:

`python MY_FLOW.py step-functions create`

this command will force the naming and will not give me the possibility to create the step function twice,
any one have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
SFN_STATE_MACHINE_PREFIX=blah python foo.py step-functions create
```

to add a custom prefix to your step-functions state-machine.

https://github.com/Netflix/metaflow/issues/372